# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecycleView

Tags: android, recycleview

Пытаюсь создать список RecyclerView. Но приложение рушится с надписью "keeps stopping"
    Лог показывает следующую ошибку:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                          Process: com.bignerdranch.android.recycleviewtran, PID: 10555
                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.recycleviewtran/com.bignerdranch.android.recycleviewtran.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecycleView

Вот грандл

```
buildscript {  
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}}allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}}task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

Причем, при попытке вставить в зависимости    "implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'" сообщает, что не может найти метод implementation и все стопорит. 
Грандл проекта

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bignerdranch.android.recycleviewtran"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'}
```

Помогите, третий день уже "на якоре"

Разметка .

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Разметка элемента списка .

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_of_good"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Ресайкл, адаптер и холдер .

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ShopAdapter mShopAdapter;
private Goods mGoods;
private ArrayOfGoods mArrayOfGoods;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    List<Goods> goodsList =mArrayOfGoods.getGoodsList();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mShopAdapter = new ShopAdapter(goodsList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mShopAdapter);

}

public class GoodsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView TitleOfGoods;
    public TextView Price;


    public GoodsHolder (View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        TitleOfGoods = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_of_good);
        Price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    }

    public void bindGoods(Goods goods) {
        mGoods = goods;
        TitleOfGoods.setText(mGoods.getTitleOfGoods());
        Price.setText(mGoods.getPrice());
    }
}

private class ShopAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GoodsHolder>{
    private List<Goods> mGoods;
    public ShopAdapter (List<Goods> goods){
        mGoods = goods;
    }

    public GoodsHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_of_goods,parent,false);
        return new GoodsHolder(view);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(GoodsHolder goodsHolder,int position){
        Goods goods = mGoods.get(position);
        goodsHolder.bindGoods(goods);
        Log.d("Testing","Checkpoint 1");
    }

    public int getItemCount(){
        return mGoods.size();
    }
}}`
```

Код списка

`public class ArrayOfGoods {

```
public ArrayOfGoods mArrayOfGoods;
public List<Goods> mGoodsList;

ArrayOfGoods() {
    mGoodsList = new ArrayList<>(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mGoodsList.add(new Goods("Товар №" + i, "100 рублей"));
    }
}

public List<Goods> getGoodsList() {
    if (mArrayOfGoods == null) {
        mArrayOfGoods = new ArrayOfGoods();
    }
    return mGoodsList;
}}`
```

код элемента списка .
`public class Goods {
    private String TitleOfGoods;
    private String Price;

```
public Goods() {

}

Goods(String TitleOfGoods, String Price) {
    this.TitleOfGoods = TitleOfGoods;
    this.Price = Price;
}

public String getTitleOfGoods() {
    return TitleOfGoods;
}

public void setTitleOfGoods(String titleOfGoods) {
    TitleOfGoods = titleOfGoods;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    Price = price;
}
```

}`

Comment: Покажите разметку

Comment: на вид все в порядке. Покажите адаптер, его инициализацию и ViwHolder. Небольшое замечание: исправьте compile на implementation (compile - выходит из образщения)

Answer (score 2):

```
Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecycleView
```

Судя по логу `RecycleView` вместо `RecyclerView`. Попробуйте `File > Invalidate Caches and restart`

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку. 
Инициализировал private ArrayOfGoods mArrayOfGoods; - то есть, со значением null.  А потом применил метод mArrayOfGoods.getGoodsList() к нулевому объекту...
    Вместо этого вызываю метод getGoodsList() непосрественно для класса: ArrayOfGoods.getGoodsList(). Соответственно, делаю getGoodsList() и сам класс статическими. 
    И проблема решается. 
    Прошу прощения, что отвлек такой фигней - азбука джавы

Comment: это все очень интересно, но никак не связано с тем, что написано в вашем вопросе, в частности с указаной вами ошибкой, решение которой в другом ответе

Comment: Да,  этот ответ тоже относится к проблеме. Оказалось две фатальных ошибки